# Raspbian Stretch: Remote ssh connection ( port forwarding ) not working

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, portforwarding

**Device**: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

**OS**: Raspbian Stretch ( no desktop ) with static ip

**Router**: Belkin F9K1103

**DNS service**: Hosting on Norwegian version of domainnameshop.com

Greetings. I'm in the process of setting up my Pi as a server. The current motive is to be able to ssh into the device from another network and host a Git server on it.

It works great at home using the local ip address, but when it comes to port forwarding port 22, NOTHING works... I've tried for at least 10 hours combined, scavenging the internet for solutions on this topic, rasbian / raspberry related port forwarding or general. Nothing seems to work. I've tried everything it seems, and no matter what i do the tests show that the port is CLOSED.

I'm currently port forwarding the Pi's local ip and port 22 on the networks port 22 ( also tried port 3322 to the pi's port 22 ) on BOTH the router and the modem using the internet provider's own service for port forwarding online ( Telenor ). The Pi is connected with an ethernet cable, and I've tried connecting it to both the router and the modem when doing all the tests. I've also tried to add 'Port 22' and 'Port 3322' in the Pi's SSH configuration file.

I've also tried to use a DNS service in which I'm forwarding my home network's ip address but still no luck.

Can anybody please help me before I go insane? I'm I missing something crucial? I can't count on both my hands how many forum posts I've been reading and guides on both raspberry or general port forwarding..

Comment: You said nothing about how you did your port forwarding? Port forward only need to be done at your router, not at your modem or Raspberry Pi. This [tutorial](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2016/11/hosting-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-part-5-dedicated-ip-domain-name-and-dns/) may be useful for you.

Comment: @hcheung As far as i know there`s few other ways to port forward other than go to the router`s ip, go to the port forward section and shoot the raspberry`s local ip and click save, right? Just thought it was kinda self explanatory so I left that part out and obviously deserve a minus one for that, thanks.. But anyways thanks for the article and effort to help but I'm afraid the port is still closed and setting up a DNS service doesn't do the trick either..

Comment: Not me that downvote you. Just to be clear. I'm trying to help based on the limited information you provided.

Comment: "It works great at home using the local ip address" means you have no problem connect to the RPi using SSH?

Comment: @hccheung My bad! And yes. Anyway I did find out what was wrong. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out what was wrong.

Our **modem** is quite new and advanced, and the internet provider has their own online admin panel for it with its own port forwarding solution and what not. So this was apparently a case of classic double NAT conflict. The **router** tries to port forward to the **modem** which would normally just bridge that onto the web, but the **modem** is in a sense being port forwarded too by the internet provider and it's own services.

What I had to do was reverting the static IP configs on the Pi, unplug it from the wifi **router**, then plug it directly to the **modem** and then port forward it using our internet providers online admin panel for the **modem**.

Now it works brilliantly.